# How to get status of the message using Send Messages with Twilio extension Firebase?

Tags: firebase, twilio

I'm trying to get the status of the message, to check is it delivered or not. I'm using firebase trigger extension, but I only get messageStatus: accepted. I configured statuscallback url in the console, but the main problem is function is not being triggered, I don't receive any updates of the message status.